# How to stop Java Result: 1 error? Why is that happening?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm working on java swing on netbeans 8.0. I'm having repeated messages when I run this code.  And finally I commented it. After that System doesn't stop working. Finally I used Task Manager and stop the whole system. Then I'm having Java Result: 1 error. 


Here is my source code.

```
public void SaveDamage(JTextField txtItID, JTextField txtInID, JTextField txtQty, JTextField txtTotal) {
    try {
        ResultSet rs1 = JDBC.getData("select inid from damage where inid='" + txtInID.getText() + "'");
        if (rs1.next()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This invoice is already finalized", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            try {
                boolean bool = JDBC.putData("insert into damage(itid, qty,total, inid) values('" + txtItID.getText() + "' , '" + txtQty.getText() + "' ,'"+txtTotal.getText()+"' , '" + txtInID.getText() + "')");
                if (bool) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "damaged saved");
                    try {
                        ResultSet rs = JDBC.getData("select avqty from item where itid='" + txtItID.getText() + "' ");
                        while (rs.first()) {
                            int newqty = rs.getInt("avqty") - Integer.valueOf(txtQty.getText());
                            try {
                                boolean bool1 = JDBC.putData("update item set avqty = '" + newqty + "' where itid = '" + txtItID.getText() + "'  ");
                                if (bool1) {
                                    // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, txtItID.getText());
                                    //  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "item updated");
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my JDBC class.

```
package Model;
//import static Model.JDBC.con;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class JDBC {
    static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/cat";
    static Connection con;
    static boolean b ;

    public  static void setCon() {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "access456");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static Connection getCon() throws Exception {
        if (con == null) {
            setCon();
        }
        return con;
    }

    public static boolean putData(String sql) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement state = getCon().prepareStatement(sql);
            state.executeUpdate();
            b = true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            b= false;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
        return b;
    }

    public static ResultSet getData(String sql) throws Exception {
        Statement state = JDBC.getCon().createStatement();
        ResultSet rset = state.executeQuery(sql);
        return rset;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you can simplify those `try`-`catch` statements into a single block since the catch is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm having repeated messages when I run this code. And finally I commented it. After that System doesn't stop working.

Change `while (rs.first())` in `while (rs.next())` because it's creating an *infinite* loop.

I suggest you to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) in proper way. since you are using PreparedStatement but still the query looks like plain Statement query.

See *Java Tutorial* on [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Read [Better Resource Management with Java SE 7: Beyond Syntactic Sugar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/trywithresources-401775.html) that presents the Java 7 answer to the automatic resource management problem.